# Determining the number of associated entries in SQL tables using Alchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables and am using SQL alchemy to find entries in one that are associated with entries in the other (let's call them `A` and `B` here).  For example all entries in `B` have an `A` ID in them

So I have a query that looks like

```
res = A.q.join(B).filter(B.relevent_data == some_data).all()
```

However when I do this there are multiple entries in B that join with the same entry in A, and when I do a filter like this I lose that count and it matters to me.  Essentially I am okay with A returning repeat entries.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How would your actual SQL query look? Remember things linke `DISTINCT` and `COUNT`.